# in jdk 'char' data type give 65, when i put 'A' at the time of type casting (narrowing)?

Tags: java

in jdk 'char' data type give 65, when i put 'A'  at the time of type casting (narrowing)?

[image]

Comment: What else did you expect?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Are you asking "if" this is what should be expected to happen, or "why" this happens (and even that is two separate questions: what is the mechanism that causes this behavior, and what is the reason it was made to behave this way)

Comment: Do not post images of code.  Copy the code into your question as text in a code formatted block.

Answer (score 1):

There's an ascii table. According to this table, the capital letter "A" has the order 65. Check this [link](http://www.asciitable.com/) for more infos.